# How to call a PHP webservice from PHONEGAP android application?

Tags: php, android, ajax, cordova

I tried [this link](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/) but I didn't get the exact methods to follow..

I create a Phonegap project following the instructions [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).

*How can I call a PHP page in my localhost using ajax?*

*Please show me the folder structure for phonegap project*

*Is there any websites to download a phonegap sample project?*

Comment: Please post the relevant code which you're using to improve this question and will help you find the answer to your problem

Comment: Hai friend..when i test the html file from which i'am calling the php file on my localhost i get an message like this below..



"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/hrmnetstratum/index.php?r=Loginregister/LoginApp."

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can call a PHP function on a phone gap application since they get installed on the client's device. Since PHP is interpreted on the server, the only way to get PHP code executed will be deploying it in a server with PHP installed.

With that being said, the way around for your problem could be:

1. Make a mobile friendly web app.
2. Load the external URL in your phone gap using `super.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");`

This might actually be towards your benefit because you don't have to write the phonegap app over and over again. You can update it easily since it will be hosted on server.

The code above was valid when I was using phonegap a while ago. It might be still valid. Try searching 'Load external webpage inside phonegap' or similar keywords on Google.
Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
formData = {
    param1: $('#param1').val(),
    param2: $('#param2').val()
}
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data);
    }
});
```